# How to get counts of a multiple fields

Tags: mysql

so I want to get a count of the terms used in my posts. Its a wordpress blog using mysql.

post 1 -> term used php
post 2 -> term used php , actionscript
post 3 -> term used php

expected result php -> 3 , actionscript -> 1

my sql query is :

```
SELECT t.name , count(*) FROM wp_terms t
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_posts p ON p.id=tr.object_id
where t.name='actionscript'  
**OR
t.name='php'**
```

Its works fine if I only give one t.name value but my requirement is for multiple value counts.

If I use the or statement it breaks. I want to avoid using php.

Comment: You should use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is 'term used php , actionscript' 1 column?

Comment: I mean are they in the same column as 1 string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT t.name , count(*) FROM wp_terms t
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_posts p ON p.id=tr.object_id
GROUP BY t.name
```